# R regmatches regexpr want to exclude delimiter

Tags: r, regex, string

I would like to extract the text in between 2 underscores for a character vector, like this one:

`text <- c("one_two_three", "a_b_c", "do_re_mi", "you_and_me", "not_this")`

The goal is to get a vector of just the middle part of each of these strings, like this:

`[1] "two" "b" "re" "and"`

I tried with regex but the underscores remained in the results, which I don't want.

```
regmatches(text, regexpr('_(.*?)_', text))
[1] "_two_" "_b_"   "_re_"  "_and_"
```

Please let me know if there is a better (non-regex) way to approach this or a way to correct the regex. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your regex pattern in `stringr::str_match` :

```
stringr::str_match(text, '_(.*?)_')[, 2]
#[1] "two" "b"   "re"  "and" NA
```

`[, 2]` part is to extract the capture group.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use ["lookaround"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), a perl regex extension:

```r
regmatches(text, regexpr('(?<=_)([^_]+)(?=_)', text, perl = TRUE))
# [1] "two" "b"   "re"  "and"
```

I also changed the inner pattern to be a little more specific: `[^_]+` one or more of non-`_` characters. `(?<=_)` means *"preceded by `_` but do not include it in the returned/consumed pattern"*, and `(?=_)` means *"followed by `_` but do not include it in the returned/consumed pattern"*. Using either one requires `perl=TRUE`, you'll get an error otherwise. (Lookaround is available in most regex functions in R. I'd say "all" but I don't know them all by heart ... so I'll say many or most for now :-)